# Character viewer missing Unicode blocks

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I just switched from OS 10.9 to OS 10.14, and the character viewer (aka "Show Emoji & Symbols") looks like this:

[image]

Where have all the other Unicode blocks (e.g. Greek and Coptic, Cyrillic, Georgian, Phonetic Symbols) gone? How do I get them back?

(Also, what do I tag this as? *keyboard* and *character* are the only two suggestions, they don't seem appropriate, but I'm out of ideas…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the three dots ••• menu at the top right.

Click Customize List…

[image: Screenshot of Character Viewer with menu showing]

Scroll down to the ones you want, select them.

[image: Screenshot of Select Categories dialog box.]

Comment: Right at the bottom, quite well hidden, is also Unicode itself, which then gives you access to the whole lot.